# Eulerian graph confusing

Tags: graph-theory, eulerian-path

Can an Eulerian graph be of edge connectivity 1?

And can an Eulerian graph have vertex connectivity 1?

Please show step how you done it.

Comment: An Eulerian graph cannot be of edge connectivity $1$, since removing and edge leaves all vertices connected by travelling the Eulerian circuit in the remaining side of the loop. It can have vertex connectivity $1$. For example, two triangles attached at a vertex.

Comment: "Please show step how you done it" is usually understood here to mean "I plan to copy your answer word-for-word and hand it in as my own work without making any effort to understand it" and that is usually not well-received here.

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to go back to your source's definition, but I wouldn't think of a graph with only an Euler trail as being Eulerian.  Any graph with an Euler circuit be such that every edge would be part of a cycle and therefore has edge connectivity greater than 1.

But an Eulerian graph can have a cut vertex.  For instance, a "bow tie graph" of two triangles that share a vertex would meet that criterion.